# Why does my caret position change mysteriously while I type?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, touchpad

I just plowed my Dell Precision M6400 laptop and installed 64-bit Windows 7.  Everything seems pretty good, except that occasionally while I am typing, my caret ends up somewhere else within the text.  This is quite irritating, since text can quickly turn to gibberish that way.  At first I thought I was just hitting the touchpad with my finger accidentally, but I am now pretty sure that's not it.

I think it might be the touchpad in some way, though.  I do not have a driver for it, and the Dell support guy basically told me tough luck until they actually start shipping Windows 7 and supporting it.  This problem does not occur when the machine's in a docking station -- it only occurs when it's standalone and I am using the laptop's keyboard, even with an external mouse.

So, how can I figure out what is causing this and fix it?  There must be a driver that worked in 64-bit Vista, since that's what I had previously, but I am unable to find it.  Dell guy wasn't too interested in this either.

Comment: Can you disable the trackpad to confirm that the problem goes away then?

Comment: I'd like to, but the default mouse driver that I have gives no way of doing that.  I can't see that Windows knows anything about it.  Are you talking about at a level beneath the OS?

Comment: no, you'll need the touchpad driver (probably Synaptics). but they haven't released any windows 7 drivers yet but the vista driver works fine (at least the x86 version i have tested): http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers

Comment: Thanks.  I did that.  The Vista 64-bit synaptics drivers installed nicely and I haven't experienced my weird caret thing since then.

Comment: Maybe molly should copy/paste her comment as the question answer.

Comment: @Matthew: I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Trackpad is one reason, most common....

Answer (score 0):

I've found with laptop keyboard that I accidentally hit the control key while typing which can, depending on what I'm actually typing, move the cursor around the document.

Comment: I thought I was causing it at first, too, but I had used this laptop for several months with Dell-installed Vista and never experienced that effect.  Nonetheless, the synaptics driver install seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Oh well - but it looks like you've found the cause anyway.

Comment: Some drivers will detect "erroneous" touches on the trackpad and ignore them..so it's possible the default one doesn't do so.